# what is going on? my workspace texture going wrong

Tags: error

[image: what is goin on?]

Does my GPU cause this? Because I got an issued with my GPU, there is something wrong like sometimes it just not responding. How can I fix it?

My laptop spec is Geforce 1050 4gb, 8gb ram, 1tb disk split d and c, Intel i7 8750h.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that sumarizes te content of the question

Comment: owh oke im sorry